# Dropdown nav menu from under navigation bar

Tags: html, css, navigation

There's a problem. When I call for nav menu in mobile view it drops down from the top of the page when I want it to dropdown from under navigation bar.
Previously I've used z-index for two neighbor blocks: `header` and `navigation`. But now in this project the backgrounds of both blocks are transparent so z-index just doesn't show to work as I mean it to. So maybe there some other hack to help with this problem?
[Here's the codepen](https://codepen.io/avalan4e/pen/YGKvGx?editors=0100) for the issue

Comment: class logo, give z-index: 5; and class navMobile give z-index: 6; with these changes I was able to make the text and hamburger Nav be over the drop-down and still keep functionality if hamburger Nav

Comment: Do you why hamburger icon goes under logo if I give class logo any z-index that is bigger then 2? I mean it becomes unclickable if logo has z-index of 3 and more (when navMobile has a greater z-index of course)

Comment: I guess that's a bug of codepen. Everything works ok on local. But that was not the point. What I need is navigation list to appear from under logo bar (not to dropdown from the top of the page). And the hack with z-index is what i did before, as I mentioned in topic. But backgrounds are transparent now. So that hack just is not for the case

Comment: chanage navigation class margin-top to 0em, and add opacity to 0 then in active class add opacity 1. the margin that you have is causing the nav top to appear from the top

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution. We better use height transition then margin for the case.
We add this props for `navigation` class

```
max-height: 0;
transition: max-height 0.15s ease-out;
overflow: hidden;
```

and the following props for `navigation active`:

```
max-height: 500px;
transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in;
```

500px for max-height is optional and I just use a value that my block will never reach.
You've got [the codepen](https://codepen.io/avalan4e/pen/YGKvGx?editors=0100) to show the details